# How to change input field placeholder to floating label by css or js

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<div class="row mg-b-25">
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="category_name" id="category_name" placeholder="Enter Category *" maxlength="50" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I want to when i focus on input filed than placeholder change to floating label

Comment: Do you mean the style like google login?

Comment: Yes , but can this be possible to use placeholder as floating label

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS :focus Selector and CSS ::placeholder Selector

Refer:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
::placeholder {
  color: red;
  opacity: 1; 
}

input:focus::placeholder  {
    color: blue;
  float:right;
  opacity: 1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<input type="text" placeholder="A placeholder text..">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Its working , but is there any way to show placeholder after enter value on input field

Answer (score 0):

Try this one example for floating label:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/css-image-filter-efmtr9?file=index.html,styles.css

Answer (score 0):

Here is a example by using [Materialize](https://materializecss.com/getting-started.html)

This example works [Here](https://c.runoob.com/front-end/61/) but I do not know why it does not work on code snippet.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="Input-Field">
<Input id="Email_input" type="Email" class="Validate" />
<Label for="Email_input">Email</Label>
</div>
</body>
<html>
```